# Some code using Dynamic fails to work inside blocks

Tags: scala, dynamic

Here's some code using `Dynamic`. As you can see, the part below works as expected.

```
scala> import language.dynamics
import language.dynamics                                                     

scala> class ExpandoObject extends Dynamic {
     |   private val dict = collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, Any]
     |   def selectDynamic(name: String): Any = dict(name)
     |   def updateDynamic(name: String)(arg: Any) = dict(name) = arg
     | }
defined class ExpandoObject

scala> val e = new ExpandoObject
e: ExpandoObject = ExpandoObject@14e03fec

scala> e.name = "rahul"
e.name: Any = rahul

scala> e.name
res62: Any = rahul
```

However when you use it in some block, it fails to work.

```
scala> {
     |   val e = new ExpandoObject
     |   e.name = "rahul"
     | }
<console>:20: error: reassignment to val
                e.name = "rahul"
                       ^

scala>
```

Again, if you call `updateDynamic` explicitly, it works.

```
scala> {
     |   val e = new ExpandoObject
     |   e.updateDynamic("name")("rahul")
     |   e
     | }
res66: ExpandoObject = ExpandoObject@3f755bd2

scala> res66.name
res67: Any = rahul
```

Is this a bug? Or something I am simply missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [regression](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5733) in earlier versions of `2.10`, before [`2.10.1-RC1`](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/1681). I was able to reproduce the issue in `2.10.0`, then ran the same code with `2.10.1`, and it worked without errors.